# Processing dynamic list view items efficiently in Android

Tags: android, multithreading, listview, android-listview, android-contacts

In my app, I have a button called "Contacts" that allows the user to select contacts to add to his or her friend list. When clicked, the user is shown a list view of all the user's contacts. Each list view row contains the contact display name, icon, email address, and a button. The name, icon, and email are all fetched using the `ContactsContract` class.

The problem I'm running into is that processing all of the user's contacts is very computationally expensive.

I tried two solutions:

1. In a `CursorAdapter`, I tried modifying the `bindView` method. I passed in a cursor that queried the user's contacts and in the `bindView` method, I executed an asynchronous call to my server to return the relation of the contact to the current user. i.e. if the contact had the app installed and was a friend, the button would display "remove". This call would determine the button type and set the appropriate `onClickListeners`.

   - This didn't work because it would cause the list to be very slow, not smooth, and feel very laggy.
2. I just tried loading the contacts and the server queries in some different thread. When it would finish loading, I would initialize a `BaseAdapter` with the the name, icon, email, and button type already determined in the different thread.

   - This didn't work because it took 30 - 40 seconds to load the contacts. However, it was much smoother once it finished loading.

How can fix this issue?

Should I get the data from the server first or pre-load it for each item in the adapter?

**Edit:**

The layout would look *similar* to this:

[image: find-friends-layout]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What i would do is to load both the contacts and the remote data, create a custom class to hold them, put it inside an `ArrayList<MyCustomContactClass>`, and only after its all ready i would load the adaptar into the listview.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I tried something similar to this. As I iterate  the contacts, I get the remote data for each contact. I have an ArrayList<ContactItem> which has icon, name, email, buttonType (buttonType is determined each iteration of the remote call). This took 30-40 seconds. Could you perhaps go into a little more detail?

Comment: I think the bottleneck is the network database pull am i right? If the server takes too long to return the contacts details we have to find out why its taking so long. If you can't speed up the server response, maybe you could grab a chunk of contacts lets say 20 contacts, load their info, show that to the user to keep him "entretained" while you load the remaining contacts server info. Other situation to keep in mind is those images you are loading, i think you should load them in a separete assynctask, after the contacts are loaded in your listview, maybe the images are the problem.

Comment: Yep. I might be able to speed the database pull up a little bit, but it probably won't be enough. I could load the first ~ 20 contacts, but I would probably run into the same issues. If I were to search or perform a fast scroll, it wouldn't be smooth. I'll also check that the images aren't the problem, but I doubt they are.

Comment: Do you wait for the images to load before showing the list?

Comment: No. In the `getView` method of my `BaseAdapter`, I load it the images using [Universal Image Loader](https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader). I have this line: `imageLoader.displayImage(items.get(position).getImageUriString(), iconImageView)`, which executes an `AsyncTask`.

Comment: Hmm, so everything is pointing to the server response time... Are you checking for each contact info individualy, or you are fetching all database result at once?

Comment: I just confirmed the problem is **not** with the images. I loaded the list view without the network request, and the list view loaded almost instantaneously and scrolled smoothly. I check each contact individually. I have a query which checks to see if the contact has the app installed, by getting the email and checking my database get the user associated with the email. If the contact has the app and is a user, I then have another server request to check the relation to the user.

Comment: Hmm, i think we've isolated the problem, if i understood correctly, for each contact, you make a server request from the app to determine its info? If that is the case, try to pull all information you need from the server all at once. Perhaps send the contacts array to the server, and get back the full contact information array.

Comment: Yeah - that's exactly what I'm doing. I'll try to implement some cloud function. I'll keep you updated. Thanks.

Comment: I managed to make the query *much* more efficient and made a cloud function to handle all the logic. Thanks for your help.